# Disable username/password Windows authentication in IIS

Tags: browser

My app web runs in my local network, I want to disable Windows authentication pop up when the website opens.

I disabled anonymous authentication and enable Windows authentication and ASP.NET impersonation.

Please help me.

Comment: Microsoft only has documentation on how to suppress the prompt for IE, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/258063/internet-explorer-may-prompt-you-for-a-password If your local users use other browsers, you need to check the relevant documentation.